# Want to add notes in a PowerPoint slides using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I want to add notes in the PowerPoint slides notes part under the PowerPoint slide using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint`.

I'm using VB.NET code. Now it is creating the [PPT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PPT_format#File_formats) file, and I can add text, comments, and images in the slide. But I need to add notes in the PowerPoint slide, in the bottom part of the slide.

Here is the code I'm using for creating slides.

```
    Dim oApp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application
    Dim oPres As Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim oSlide As Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Slide
    Dim bAssistantOn As Boolean
    Const sTemplate = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Templates\Presentation Designs\ContemporaryPhotoAlbum.potx"
    Const sPic = "C:\WINDOWS\Soap Bubbles.bmp"
    oApp = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application()
    oApp.Visible = True
    oApp.WindowState = Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpWindowState.ppWindowMaximized
    oApp.Visible = True
    oPres = oApp.Presentations.Open(sTemplate, , , True)
    oPres = oApp.Presentations.Add(Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoCTrue)
    oSlide = oPres.Slides.Add(1, PpSlideLayout.ppLayoutVerticalTitleAndText)
    oSlide.Comments.Add(1, 1, "f", "sf", "sdfgdfg")
    With (oSlide.Shapes.Item(1).TextFrame.TextRange)
        .Text = "Aspire Software Consultancy"
        .Font.Name = "Comic Sans MS"
        .Font.Size = 48
    End With
    oSlide.Shapes.AddPicture(sPic, False, True, 150, 150, 500, 350)
    oSlide = oPres.Slides.Add(2, Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpSlideLayout.ppLayoutTitleOnly)
    With oSlide.Shapes.Item(1).TextFrame.TextRange
        .Text = "My Chart"
        .Font.Name = "Comic Sans MS"
        .Font.Size = 48
    End With
    oSlide.NotesPage.Comments.Add(4, 4, "asd", "a", "gooooooood")
    oSlide = oPres.Slides.Add(3, Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpSlideLayout.ppLayoutBlank)
    oSlide.FollowMasterBackground = False
    Dim oShape As Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shape
    oShape = oSlide.Shapes.AddTextEffect(Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoPresetTextEffect.msoTextEffect27,
        "The End", "Impact", 96, False, False, 230, 200)
    oShape.Shadow.ForeColor.SchemeColor = Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpColorSchemeIndex.ppForeground
    oShape.Shadow.Visible = True
    oShape.Shadow.OffsetX = 3
    oShape.Shadow.OffsetY = 3
    oShape = Nothing
    oSlide = Nothing

    Dim SlideIdx(3) As Integer
    SlideIdx(0) = 1
    SlideIdx(1) = 2
    SlideIdx(2) = 3
    With oPres.Slides.Range(SlideIdx).SlideShowTransition
        .AdvanceOnTime = True
        .AdvanceTime = 3
        .EntryEffect = Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpEntryEffect.ppEffectBoxOut
    End With
    Dim oSettings As Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.SlideShowSettings
    oSettings = oPres.SlideShowSettings
    oSettings.StartingSlide = 1
    oSettings.EndingSlide = 3
    bAssistantOn = oApp.Assistant.On
    oApp.Assistant.On = False
    oSettings.Run()
    Do While oApp.SlideShowWindows.Count >= 1
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()
    Loop
    oSettings = Nothing
    If bAssistantOn Then
        oApp.Assistant.On = True
        oApp.Assistant.Visible = False
    End If
    oPres.Save()
    oPres.SaveAs("c:\aspire", PpSaveAsFileType.ppSaveAsPresentation, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue)
    oPres.Saved = True
    oPres.Close()
    oPres = Nothing
    oApp.Quit()
    oApp = Nothing
```

Answer (score 3):

I found the following solution and it works for me:

```
if (slide.NotesPage.Shapes.Count == 0)
{
    slide.NotesPage.Shapes.AddShape(MsoAutoShapeType.msoShapeRectangle, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    var footerShape = slide.NotesPage.Shapes[1];
    footerShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "your note text";
}
else
{
    foreach (PowerPoint.Shape shape in slide.NotesPage.Shapes)
    {
        if (shape.HasTextFrame == MsoTriState.msoTrue)
            if (shape.TextFrame.HasText == MsoTriState.msoTrue)
                shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "yout note text";
    }
}
```